# EBICS 3.0 Schema H005 Ebics errorcode 090004

Tags: xml, payment, banking

I try to implement a Ebics 3.0 (H005) solution, but have an issue when sending the INI ordertype request to the server.
I get the errorcode: 090004 which means "Invalid Order Data Format".
Unfortunately I have not been able to get a helpful response from the bank, so I hope somebody here can assist me.
All parameters used in the xml documents is ofcourse changed to testvalues, and the certificate is only created for this post.

I send the following ebicsUnsecuredRequest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ebicsUnsecuredRequest Version="H005" Revision="1" xmlns="urn:org:ebics:H005" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ebics.org/S002">
    <header authenticate="true">
        <static>
            <HostID>DEHost</HostID>
            <PartnerID>DEPartner</PartnerID>
            <UserID>DeSystemUser</UserID>
            <Product Language="de">Ebics server</Product>
            <OrderDetails xsi:type="UnsecuredReqOrderDetailsType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <AdminOrderType>INI</AdminOrderType>
            </OrderDetails>
            <SecurityMedium>0000</SecurityMedium>
        </static>
        <mutable/>
    </header>
    <body>
        <DataTransfer>
            <OrderData>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</OrderData>
        </DataTransfer>
    </body>
</ebicsUnsecuredRequest>
```

Contained herein I have the SignaturePubKeyOrderData, which is compressed and base64 encrypted and inserted into the orderdetails element above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:SignaturePubKeyOrderData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns2="http://www.ebics.org/S002">
    <ns2:SignaturePubKeyInfo>
        <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
            <X509IssuerSerial>
                <X509IssuerName>L=Sydhavn, C=DK, CN=*.example.com, O=Claus AS, OU=eng</X509IssuerName>
                <X509SerialNumber>1697464111985</X509SerialNumber>
            </X509IssuerSerial>
        </X509Data>
        <ns2:SignatureVersion>A005</ns2:SignatureVersion>
    </ns2:SignaturePubKeyInfo>
    <ns2:PartnerID>DEPartner</ns2:PartnerID>
    <ns2:UserID>DeSystemUser</ns2:UserID>
</ns2:SignaturePubKeyOrderData>
```

The A005 certificate is as follows in PEM format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas what could be the issue.
If you have your own solution that works, it would be great if you can send me an example of a ebicsUnsecuredRequest that works.

Comment: I've found the specification which is from 2011.  The encryption mode may of changed.  Check the encryption mode in the certificate.  See if it matches the specification https://www.cfonb.org/fichiers/20130612170023_6_4_EBICS_Specification_2.5_final_2011_05_16_2012_07_01.pdf.  The may be a new specification.  Here is latest specification from 2022 : https://www.ebics.org/en/technical-information/ebics-specification

Comment: Read chapter 14 for electronic signature.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I will take a look into the specification there might be something i missed.

Comment: Make sure the URI (schema) that is being used matches the encryption algorithm of the certificate.  See : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/6.1?topic=security-how-it-works-signing-soap-messages#integrity-soap__title__2